# C++ exception access violation

Tags: c++, exception, access-violation

this code runs correctly but at a unspecific moment im getting an **exception access violation** at line

```
return lhs.getGeneralType()->getID() != rhs.getGeneralType()->getID();
```

and the error breaks my application... ive already tried to compile with **/EHa** but the error

repeating... this line of code runs correctly many times and after some time this error occurs..

```
if (lhs.getType() == rhs.getType()) {

    try {

        if (lhs.getGeneralType() != NULL && lhs.getGeneralType() != NULL)
            return lhs.getGeneralType()->getID() != rhs.getGeneralType()->getID();
        else if (lhs.getGeneralType() == NULL && lhs.getGeneralType() == NULL)
            return false;
        else if (lhs.getGeneralType() != NULL && lhs.getGeneralType() == NULL)
            return false;
        else if (lhs.getGeneralType() == NULL && lhs.getGeneralType() != NULL)
            return true;
        else
            return true;

    } catch(char * e) { // tried also exception & , char* e
        return true;
    }   
} else
    return true;
```

the definition of Type which getGeneralType() returns is that below

```
  class Type
  {
  private:
    int _id;
  public:
    Type(int id);
    operator int() const;
    int getID() const;
  };
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like a spelling mistake in the if-statements

```
if (lhs.getGeneralType() != NULL && lhs.getGeneralType() != NULL)
```

One of the `lhs`'s should probably be `rhs`.

Answer (score 3):

```
if (lhs.getGeneralType() != NULL && lhs.getGeneralType() != NULL)
```

You have a copy-and-paste error. That should be:

```
if (lhs.getGeneralType() != NULL && rhs.getGeneralType() != NULL)
                                    ^
```

and similarly for the other comparisons.

As a result of that, you were referencing a null pointer, giving undefined behaviour; in this case, an access violation. This is not a C++ exception and so cannot be handled with a `catch` block. I believe Microsoft's dialect of C++ offers some non-standard way to catch and recover from these (`__try` and `__catch`, possibly), but it's much better to fix the bug than to use that kind of nonsense.